# How do I get the video media path in a theme?

Tags: theming

I want to embed a video on a page.

How do I display the field_media_video_embed_field in my twig?

The complicated thing about this is that I am using a view inside tabs.

`{{ kint(programme.video) }}` gives me the following output.

> [image: screenshot]

In my theme I have used the following code.

```php
$programmes = [];
$view = Views::getView('participating_programmes');
$view->execute();
foreach ($view->result as $row) {
  $video = $row->_entity->get('field_pvideo')->referencedEntities();
  $programmes[$nid]['video'] = $video;
}
```

Ideally I want to embed the video, but I would be happy if I could just get the field_media_video_embed_field and work from there.

Comment: Try `{{ kint(programme.video.field_media_video_embed_field.value) }}`

Comment: Sorry, that returns NULL

Comment: The comment is correct about the field value. The problem is that referencedEntities() returns an array when you probably only want a single entity. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want to get one or multiple videos:

```
// get one video media entity
$video = $row->_entity->get('field_pvideo')->entity;
// get multiple video media entities
$videos = $row->_entity->get('field_pvideo')->referencedEntities();
```

Then in Twig for one video:

```
{{ programme.video.field_media_video_embed_field.value }}
```

or multiple videos:

```
{% for video in programme.videos %}
  {{ video.field_media_video_embed_field.value }}
{% endfor %}
```